# How to get a relative layout height to wrap around a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to get a relative layout to wrap around a button. It looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Theme.MyCompany.Button.Container"
            android:layout_weight="10">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@style/Theme.MyCompany.Button.MyList"
                android:id="@+id/this is my button"
                android:text="@string/this_is_my_button"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

It wraps fine in terms of the width, but the height reaches up to the above LinearLayout.

I tried to hack through it by create a button theme with the color white, but it just creates a lighter view.

How can I get this button to appear at the bottom of the page, with or without the benefit of a container?

Comment: Where is this fabled "LinearLayout"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you nee to move this line `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to the relative layout

So something like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Theme.MyCompany.Button.Container"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/Theme.MyCompany.Button.MyList"
            android:id="@+id/this is my button"
            android:text="@string/this_is_my_button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out Just update the Relative layout's "android:layout_height" --

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/Theme.MyCompany.Button.Container"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/Theme.MyCompany.Button.MyList"
            android:id="@+id/this is my button"
            android:text="@string/this_is_my_button"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Changes In Your Code, Try This

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout  //this will wrap your button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="10" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/this is my button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="this_is_my_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```